# How to store value from for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I want to store value of `x_error`, `y_error`, and `z_error` in the following:

```
for i=1:0.1:5

    ly=i;

    for j=1:0.1:5;

        lx=j;

        c1=co1(x1,y1,z1,lx,ly,lz,f);
        c2=co2(x2,y2,z1,lx,ly,lz,f);
        c3=co3(x3,y3,z1,lx,ly,lz,f);

        %options = optimoptions('fsolve','Display','iter');

        func = @(x)efunction(x,x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3,c1,c2,c3,f);

        [x,fval] = fsolve(func,x0);


        X=x(1,1);
        Y=x(1,2);
        H=x(1,3);

        x_error= sprintf('%.10f',abs(X-lx));
        y_error=sprintf('%.10f',abs(Y-ly));
        z_error=sprintf('%.10f',abs((z1-H)-lz));

    end

end
```

I want to store all the value of `x_error`, `y_error` and `z_error`.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the strings in cell arrays:

```
% init arrays
num_iterations = size(1:0.1:5, 2);
x_errors = cell(num_iterations,1);
y_errors = cell(num_iterations,1);
z_errors = cell(num_iterations,1);

for j=1:0.1:5;

    % some code
    % ...


    x_error= sprintf('%.10f',abs(X-lx));
    y_error=sprintf('%.10f',abs(Y-ly));
    z_error=sprintf('%.10f',abs((z1-H)-lz));

    store_index = int32(j*10) - 9;
    x_errors{store_index} = x_error;
    y_errors{store_index} = y_error;
    z_errors{store_index} = z_error;
end
```

HOWEVER, I would advise to store the numeric values of the errors in regular arrays, and formatting them with `sprintf` afterwards if/when needed.

To store the numeric values you'd do

```
% init/allocate memory
num_iterations = size(1:0.1:5, 2);
x_errors = zeros(num_iterations,1);
% ...
x_error = abs(X-lx);
% ...
x_errors(store_index) = x_error;
```

Comment: here, x_error or y_error, z_error only give 41 values while my value should me 1681 values in each, i am also not sure this 42 values are which point values.                                                  why need to use this, its not clear to me store_index = int32(j*10) - 9;

Comment: @user3506750 I did not see that there was another for-loop around your code because of the broken formatting (thanks Manishika for fixing this). However, regardless of the amount of values you need to store, the concept of how you can do it stays the same. What are you having problems with? The calculation j*10 - 9 is done because your loop variable increments in steps of 0.1 and therefore cannot be used as an index for the array which holds the errors without making a whole number out of it first.